# Solr TermVector results not returning

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I am having an issue with Solr TermVector queries - The term vector is not being returned but I can see it using Luke.
My query and response (there is one document in my index) -

.../solr/select/?qt=tvrh&q=id:95&tv.all=true&tv.fl=text

```
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
 <str name="id">95</str>
 <str name="unique_file_id">asdf4f4fef</str>
 <arr name="text">
  <str>network network stuff stuff stuff word</str>
  <str>asdfdasf.pdf</str>
 </arr>....
```

The field declaration in the schema -

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
```

When I execute

.../solr/admin/luke?id=95

I can see the term vector component for field text -

```
<lst name="text">
...
<str name="value">network network stuff stuff stuff word</str>
...
<lst name="termVector">
 <int name="asdfdasf.pdf">1</int>
 <int name="network">2</int>
 <int name="stuff">3</int>
 <int name="word">1</int>
</lst>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of /solr/select and adding the qt, try /solr/tvrh

Comment: this works. [link](/solr/tvrh/?&q=id:95&tv.all=true&tv.fl=text). Seems documentation is not updated properly.